# Selenium PhantomJS unable to find elements on page because page is blank

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

Whenever I run my python selenium test case I get this error:

`NoSuchElementException: Message: {"errorMessage":"Unable to find element with name... etc`

^^ I can't locate the username field because the page is not loading.

I am able to return the url and it is the correct url.
Whenever I save a screenshot of the login page, it returns a solid white page. PhantomJS is going to the correct address but not loading the page. It looks like this is only happening with https sites and not http.

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_args=['--ignore-ssl-errors=true', '--  ssl-protocol=any'])


class TestOne(unittest.TestCase):

def setUp(self):
    self.driver = browser
    self.driver.set_window_size(2000, 1500)

def test_url(self):
    driver = self.driver
    self.driver.get("https://urlhere")
    print driver.current_url
    driver.save_screenshot("path/toscreenshot/screenshot1")
    driver.implicitly_wait(30)
    driver.find_element_by_name("username").clear()
    driver.find_element_by_name("username").send_keys("username")
    driver.find_element_by_name("password").clear()
    driver.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys("password")
    driver.find_element_by_name("submit").click()

    # End of login

def tearDown(self):
    self.driver.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
unittest.main()
```

Comment: Add `--ssl-protocol=tlsv1` to phantomjs argument instead of `--ssl-protocol=any`

Comment: I'm still getting the same results.